# Key with zero value shifts to last in array while looping

Tags: jquery, json

I am having an jsonobject like

```
{
2004-Uneducated:100
2005-Uneducated:0
2008-Uneducated:200
2009-Uneducated:150
}
```

after parsing and iterating using $.each
the values with zero get shifted to last like

```
   {
    2004-Uneducated:100  
    2008-Uneducated:200
    2009-Uneducated:150
    2005-Uneducated:0
    }
```

Why is it happening how can I maintain the same order.
Please help.

Comment: A JavaScript Object is a collection of "unordered" properties. If you want to maintain the order, use Array instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ordered list of things, use an array.

And since you seem to capture different properties in each element, use an array of objects:

```
[
    {year: 2004, label: "Uneducated", value: 100},
    {year: 2005, label: "Uneducated", value: 0},
    {year: 2008, label: "Uneducated", value: 200},
    {year: 2009, label: "Uneducated", value: 150}
]
```

Objects do not guarantee key order, they only guarantee key uniqueness. They are the wrong data structure for your task.